# doInBackground does not set the value of the string on the first click of a button but executed the second click

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why my asynctask doesnt executed on the first button click but does in the second click

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class Asynctask_kwh_used extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            sqLiteDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT '"+ etext1.getText().toString() +"' - last_record * "+Multiplier+" FROM Consumer WHERE account_no = '" + account_no.getText().toString() + "'", null);
            while (cursor1.moveToNext())
            {
                s1= cursor1.getString(0);
            }
            cursor1.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Log**
**It seems that the doInbackground is executed after my if statement but I put the asynctask method before that**

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
        at com.vicjames.qiimeterreader.ManageReading$6$1.run(ManageReading.java:360)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
D/Surface: lockCanvas
D/Surface: lockCanvas
V/TAG: doInbackground
```

**It points to this line**

```
if (Double.parseDouble(s1) > (Double.parseDouble(s2) * 1.5) || Double.parseDouble(s1) < 0)
```

---

Comment: Please post the full logcat.

Comment: What makes you think your task is not executed? You did not tell what should happen and what you see instead. Further nobody knows when you try to use s1 and s2. So what is this all about?